# Converting an Enum type to IList

Tags: c#, ienumerable, menu, ilist

Hi
How can I convert an `enum` to `IList`?
Suppose you want to read all elements in `FormWindowState` enum, and return an `IList<FormWindowState>` containing `Normal`, `Minimized` and `Maximized`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Enum.GetValues()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx). For example:

```
var list = (IList<FormWindowState>) Enum.GetValues(typeof(FormWindowState));
```

It actually returns a `FormWindowState[]` but that implements `IList<T>` appropriately anyway.

If you're doing a lot of work with enums and you want a more type-safe approach, you may want to look at my [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) project too.

Comment: Isn´t it better to use: 
var list =  (IList<FormWindowState>) Enum.GetValues(typeof(FormWindowState)).Cast<FormWindowState>();

Answer (score 0):

```
IList<FormWindowState> myList;//instantiate it with a concrete collection.


myList.Add(FormWindowsState.Normal);
myList.Add(FormWindowsState.Minimized);
myList.Add(FormWindowsState.Maximized);
```

This is just for this case, when you have only 3 enum members. Otherwise use the solution of Jon Skeet.

Comment: If you *did* want to explicitly add them, it would at least be nicer to use a collection initializer instead of explicit Add calls.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I am still working mostly with .NET 2.0 and not used that much to use the new language features. +1 for comment also.

Comment: You can still use collection initializers in .NET 2.0 so long as you're building with the C# 3 compiler. If you're using VS2005, you have my sympathies :(